# Magento 2 how to add if or else statement to email template?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, transactional-mail, template-directive

I want to add an if or else statement to the invoice email template to check if the order shipping method is courier delivery order or self pick up order. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

The conditonal syntax in email templates is the same as Magento 1.

Thus in your email template you can do stuff like this for example:

```
{{if logo_width}}
    width="{{var logo_width}}"
{{else}}
    width="200"
{{/if}}
```

You can find more information in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Comment: How to check if logo_width > 250?

Answer (score 2):

This is the same concept as magento 1,

Example:

```
{{if logo_width}}
    width="{{var logo_width}}"
{{else}}
    width="200"
{{/if}}

{{if logo_height}}
    height="{{var logo_height}}"
{{else}}
    height="100"
{{/if}}
```

Above example just demo purpose Check the width and height attributes of the **`img`** tag to reflect the area in which you want your logo to display (for example, 200 × 100).

Comment: How to check if width> 250 ?

Comment: @jafarpinjar I don't think you can use if/else condition to check values. However, you can call a custom Block inside your email template and put your logic in the custom Block as suggested by: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161041/magento-2-emails-if-statement