# Magento 2 - Emails -> if statement

Tags: magento2, email, custom

I'm currently configuring my transactional emails for Magento 2 and since I am in germany and want to ship some parts to a partner inside the EU i can place those orders without calculating taxes for that.

Therefore my EU partners have an own customer group without any tax display.

So make everything clear and don't get in trouble with the Tax institute here in germany i have to declare those orders with an special text inside the email and invoice.pdf.

Is there any way to implement an `if-statement` to call something like:

`if customergroup == EU_Partner then display TEXT` ?

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**

I found something while searching for a solution.

`{{depend order.customer_group_id}} TEXT {{/depend}}`

Does this work on Magento 2 and if so, how do i declare the `customer_group_id` ?

Comment: are you talking about in email template in backend?

Comment: yes. I want to change the template with a custom variable or block which gets displayed if the customer got a specific group.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We cannot use the `if` condition like:

```
{{if order.customer_group_id == 1}}
     <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
{{/if}}
```

We can find the customer group id in `sales_order` table. I also notice that the customer group id is a int type.

1. In your case, we can use `if` and `depend` directives. However, we need to set a "flag" for our special case to order Object (for example: `Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage::saveOrder()`).

For example:

```
//We need to check if the order has EU customer
$order->setData('eu_customer');
```

In your email, we can check property directly:

```
{{if order.eu_customer}}
     <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
{{/if}}
```

2. We can use block technique. For example, insert this block in your template:

   {{block class='Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template'
   area='frontend' template='Vendor_Module::email/specificcustomer/info.phtml' order=$order}}

In your custom template, we can check whatever you want.

```
<?php if($this->getData('order')->getCustomerGroupId()==1) {
        echo "<p>Bla Bla Bla</p>"; 
      }
?>
```

See more here: `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new.html`

Comment: You are my hero. The Block-technique work perfect, thanks alot :)

Comment: The option #1 worked for me. Many thanks for the input.

Comment: Magento 1 Like same how can i add website filter in email template like if website id == 1 first condition  else second condition thank you @Khoa TruongDinh

Comment: could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694678/active-an-extension-based-on-condition-in-magento-2

Comment: Could you show me where can I add the custom info.phtml?

Comment: I got this error: Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'Custom_Module::email/info.html' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'

Answer (score 4):

Following are the solutions for new version

**Solution 1:** use depend tag which check whether that variable has some value or not. You will need to add following code in your email template

```
{{depend shipping_company}}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
               <h1>Your shipment is on its way.</h1>
           </td>
           <td>
             <img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/logo-dpd.png}}" alt="" />
           </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
   </tr>
 {{/depend}}
```

**Solution 2: Block technique for advance conditioning**

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' 
               area='frontend' template='Codedecorator_Learn::email/shipping_company.phtml' shipping_company=$shipping_company}}
```

Add above block code in your email template and create new phtml template in your plugin like following:

```
  <?php 
            if($block->getData('shipping_company') !='dpd') {
                    echo $block->getData('shipping_company'); 
            

}?>
```

for more detail you can visit following [blog](https://www.codedecorator.com/blog/how-to-add-if-condition-in-transactional-emails/)