# Which event observer will be triggered before customer mail send in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, email

I need to **assign value to my custom variable in new customer Email template**.
For that I need to know which Event Observer will be triggered before customer mail send.

Comment: There is no such events for this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html When u want to use your Event please give more detail

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 1):

1) Recommend you to **use Plugin** in Magento 2:

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php::execute()`

```
 $customer = $this->accountManagement
                ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);
```

As we can see, the method `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php::createAccount()` is used creating customer account and performing necessary business operations like sending email.

For sending email with new account related information, `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php::newAccount()` will be called (The sending email method can be changed in the later version of Magento).

*app/code/Vendor/Customer/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotificationInterface">
        <plugin name="add_data_to_customer"
                type="Vendor\Customer\Model\Plugin\AddDataToEmailNotification"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Our custom Plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Model\Plugin;

class AddDataToEmailNotification
{
    public function beforeNewAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotificationInterface $emailNotification,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer,
        $type,
        $backUrl,
        $storeId,
        $sendemailStoreId

    )
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

2) **Block Technique**: we can read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161080/33057

**NOTE:** My Magento version is 2.1.3, there are some deprecated methods. I will update later.

Comment: I used it, but haven't work