# Magento 1.9 - Custom message display at PDP page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, php-7, if

I need to display delivery information on PDP page **(app\design\frontend\default\theme\template\catalog\product)**

If SKU **66** the product delivery information is **5 To 15 Business Days** 
For other product the delivery information is **15 To 30 Business Days**

My condition:

```
    <?php 
        $_sku = '66';

        if($_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_sku))
        : ?>

            <b><?php echo $this->__('5 To 15 Business Days') ?></b>

            <?php else : ?>

            <b><?php echo $this->__('15 To 30 Business Days') ?></b>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Full Code:

```
/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 * @see Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
 */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="product-img-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="product-shop">
            <div class="product-name">
                <h1 itemprop="name"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            </div>

             <?php  
             // $collection = Mage::getModel('shippingrestriction/shippingzip')->getCollection();


            ?>

            <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
                <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?> 


            <?php 
                $_sku = '66';

                if($_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_sku))
                {  ?>

                    <b><?php echo $this->__('5 To 15 Business Days') ?></b>

                    <?php else : ?>

                    <b><?php echo $this->__('15 To 30 Business Days') ?></b>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php } ?>




            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                    <div class="std" itemprop="description"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <div class="row-product">
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>

                <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                    <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

        </div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
        <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
                <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
                    <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
                    <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php echo $html; ?>
                </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
        <?php $attStuff= $_product->getData(); ?>
        <?php if( !empty( $attStuff['videoid'] ) ): ?>        
            <div class="video-box box-collateral">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Video') ?></h2>  
                <div class="box-collateral-content">
                    <div class="video">
                         <iframe src="<?php echo $attStuff['videoid']; ?>?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>     
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

How to modify my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do only a test about giving sky something like this:

```
/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 * @see Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
 */
?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if($_product->getSku() == 66): ?>
    <b><?php echo $this->__('5 To 15 Business Days') ?></b>
<?php else : ?>
    <b><?php echo $this->__('15 To 30 Business Days') ?></b>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: May i know what is the difference between " { " and " : "

Comment: Why we need to declare this => <?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>   Help me thanks.

Comment: More than one sku means how can i declare here => <?php if($_product->getSku() == 66): ?>

Comment: Helper not required you can remove it (for more skus) di this (<?php if( in_array($_product->getSku(), array(66, 22)): ?> )

Comment: I just tried same for website filter inside my phtml file, https://paste.ofcode.org/G7k6QZMMEMHE8yHCH3kj6z getting error, can i get help?  line 31 - 42 @Mohamed El Mrabet

Comment: I just tried the same for website filter inside my Html file, https://paste.ofcode.org/G7k6QZMMEMHE8yHCH3kj6z getting an error, can i get help? line 31 - 42 @Mohamed El Mrabet

Comment: Its a email template not a phtml you can't set php code in template

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161041/magento-2-emails-if-statement

Comment: Can i copy css from skin\frontend\base\default\css\email-inline.css to skin\frontend\default\theme\css\email-inline.css and change some css effect is itrecommend way?

Comment: Yes non problem

Comment: Just curiosity, this is called in Magento 2 as preference like update core files instead of edit in theme or module?

Comment: No its a rewrite