# Where can I find the full syntax specification for Markup Tags (double curly braces)?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, documentation

I have found some documentation for Magento's [Markup Tags](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/markup-tags.html), but nothing that would appear to be complete. For search-ability, I've also seen them described as "double curly brace syntax", "double curly bracket syntax", and "short codes".

- [Magento Docs / User-Guide / Marketing / Markup
  Tags](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/markup-tags.html)

  - Provides some examples inserting custom variables, urls, blocks, and widgets.
- [Magento Docs / Frontend Developer Guide / Templates / Email Templates](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html)

  - This Email Templates page provides several examples, but does not call them "Markup Tags", or refer to any language in particular, simply the directives in those examples, such as...

    - "...**these two directives**: `{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}` and..."
    - "...the Store Hours (`{{config path="general/store_information/hours"}}`) **variable**..."
    - "...**an inlinecss directive**: `{{inlinecss file="css/email-inline.css"}}`..."
    - "Example: ... `{{if logo_width}}` ... the if/else **conditional statement**..."

I need to edit some email templates, and would like to know my options, before prodding it with trial and error. Looking for documentation details that could answer several questions such as:

- Is this a specific markup/templating language?
- Is "*if-then-else*" the only flow control, or are there other conditionals? "*else-if*"? "*switch*"?
- I've only seen if statement examples with relational operators — are arithmetic and logical operators allowed?

Thank you!
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a specific markup/templating language?

No. The only way i can describe it is html markup with dynamic tags

> Is "if-then-else" the only flow control, or are there other conditionals? "else-if"? "switch"?

No. You either need to stack if statements or render block logic and handle all your conditional stuff inside the block logic.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161080/70343

> I've only seen if statement examples with relational operators — are arithmetic and logical operators allowed?

No. Same as above.